# How do you display cross-contact searches?

Tags: relationships, export

I am trying to create a CSV using both Individual contact and Organisation contact information and I am having difficulty trying to achieve this.

As it's most basic it is to print postal labels containing:

- The Individual with a specific relationship (there is only one per Organisation)
- The Organisation display name
- The Organisation address

The way that I thought most logical to do this is:

1. Open the Smart Group with all the organisations (filtered by the organisations membership status)
2. "Select All" and "Export Contacts"
3. Include field "Individual" > "Relationship (under related info for)
4. Include the Organisation fields

The exported file leaves the individual field blank though.

I am using Civi 4.4.14 and Drupal 7.39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a smart group of the indiviuals - you should be able to search for all individuals with that particular relationship. You can then export the contact info.

When exporting, you'll need to select 'Individual' > Relatonship (e.g. 'Employee of')' > Organisation details for each of the address fields

Actually, thinking about it, that might be the problem with your attempt - try selecting the export field 'Organisation' > Relationship (e.g. 'Employer of') > Individual details.